# Stream File Contents Until Substring Encountered

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I was using:

```
bash $ head -n 2 *.xml | grep (..stuff..)
```

to stream first 2 lines of all xml files to grep command. However, I realized that this was not reliable for the structure of these files.

What I need instead is to stream start of each xml file until a particular substring (which all these files have) is encountered.

head does not provide that level of granularity. The substring is simply the start of a tag (e.g. something like "< tag start"). I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: try `tail -F *.xml |grep -m1 'stuff'` this will keep tailing all xml in the directory and exit once stuff is seen in any one of the file.

Comment: `sed -e '/stuff/q'` maybe?  (Though in testing, it also prints the line that matches.)

Comment: If you want to exclude the matching line, looks like `sed -n -e '/stuff/q; p'` works.

Comment: When you say `stream` - does that imply your XML files are being written to while you're reading them?

Comment: The problem can be easily resolved with a XML parser... but think that `grep(1)` is a line based program, and your file can have the sequence encoded in separate lines for the `<` and the tag name.  You'd need to check that appropiate whitespace is in between both and that the tag selected is not a prefix of another structure.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Schepler for all the replies. Unfortunately I cannot get any of them to work. Maybe I am misunderstanding or my post was incorrectly written. The sed solution above seems suspended when I attempt: sed -d '<mt:myEndTag/q' (where <mt:myEndTag is what I want excluded. Also the sed solution does not address going through all xml files (*.xml)

Comment: Thanks @PS, however the tail command, even before the pipe is streaming the wrong parts of the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the max number of lines you have before the matching string you can do something like this:

```
# cat testfile 
123
9
1
1
2
3
4000
TAG
456
# grep -m 1 -B 10 TAG testfile | grep -v TAG
123
9
1
1
2
3
4000
#
```

Comment: thanks @accdias . This is very promising but not quite working for my situation. It seems to be returning stuff even after the start tag. I can't provide the actual file so creating a test one would be too much work. I think I should have simply asked for command that streams ONLY text between a given start and end tag (e.g. "<mt:myTag LOTSOFSTUFF >" so that only LOTSOFSTUFF is streamed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want either of these (using GNU awk for `nextfile`) depending on if you want the tag line printed or not:

```
awk '/< tag start/{nextfile} 1' *.xml

awk '1; /< tag start/{nextfile}' *.xml
```

or less efficiently with any awk:

```
awk 'FNR==1{f=1} /< tag start/{f=0} f' *.xml

awk 'FNR==1{f=1} f; /< tag start/{f=0}' *.xml
```

or bringing back some efficiency in this case:

```
for file in *.xml; do
    awk '/< tag start/{exit} 1' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the responses. I found that really I only needed the content of a single tag, rather than from the beginning of the xml files. This simplified the parsing. So for instance:

```
<mt:myTag LOTSOFSTUFF >"
```

, I really only needed LOTSOFSTUFF. So I simply did:

```
grep -oP "<mt:myTag(.*)>" *.xml | grep_more
```

and that worked exactly. Thanks again. I really appreciated and sorry I did not realize my use case was simpler than I made it out to  be.